# An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in .DLL but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I am getting this error message at runtime when I zoom in an Image.

here is XAML code

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
            <toolkit:GestureListener 
                PinchStarted="OnPinchStarted"
                PinchDelta="OnPinchDelta"
                DragDelta="OnDragDelta"
                Flick="GestureListener_Flick">
            </toolkit:GestureListener>
        </toolkit:GestureService.GestureListener>
        <Image x:Name="ImgZoom" Source="Image.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="480" Height="770" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
</Grid>
```

[image: Getting this exception]

Comment: If you look at the details of the exception, you'll see what the transform type *actually* was. Why did you expect that it would be a CompositeTransform?

Comment: You have not defined a RenderTransform, you must define one in your xaml

Comment: Thank you very very much Shawn Kendrot. I have forget to define RenderTransform thank you very much

Comment: & thank you too Jon Skeet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define the RenderTransform within your xaml

```
<Image x:Name="ImgZoom" Source="Image.jpg" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="480" Height="770" Stretch="Fill"  Margin="0,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Image.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform/>
    </Image.RenderTransform>
</Image>
```